# "Unexpected type" error

Tags: java, compilation

I'm having a problem compiling my Java program:

```
\Desktop\Java Programming\JFrameWithPanel.java:79: unexpected type
required: variable
found   : value
            if(serviceTerms.isSelected() = false)
                                      ^
1 error
```

What is causing this error?

```
public class JFrameWithPanel extends JFrame implements ActionListener, ItemListener
{
    int packageIndex;
    double price;
    double[] prices = {49.99, 39.99, 34.99, 99.99};

    DecimalFormat money = new DecimalFormat("$0.00");
    JLabel priceLabel = new JLabel("Total Price: "+price);
    JButton button = new JButton("Check Price");
    JComboBox packageChoice = new JComboBox();
    JPanel pane = new JPanel();
    TextField text = new TextField(5);
    JButton accept = new JButton("Accept");
    JButton decline = new JButton("Decline");
    JCheckBox serviceTerms = new JCheckBox("I Agree to the Terms of Service.", false);
    JTextArea termsOfService = new JTextArea("This is a text area", 5, 10);


    public JFrameWithPanel()
    {
        super("JFrame with Panel");

        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        pane.add(packageChoice);
        setContentPane(pane);
        setSize(250,250);
        setVisible(true);

        packageChoice.addItem("A+ Certification");
        packageChoice.addItem("Network+ Certification ");
        packageChoice.addItem("Security+ Certifictation");
        packageChoice.addItem("CIT Full Test Package");

        pane.add(button);
        button.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(text);
        text.setEditable(false);
        text.setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        text.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(termsOfService);
        termsOfService.setEditable(false);
        termsOfService.setBackground(Color.lightGray);

        pane.add(serviceTerms);
        serviceTerms.addItemListener(this);

        pane.add(accept);
        accept.addActionListener(this);

        pane.add(decline);
        decline.addActionListener(this);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
    {
        packageIndex = packageChoice.getSelectedIndex();
        price = prices[packageIndex];
        text.setText("$"+price);

        Object source = e.getSource();

        if(source == accept)
        {
            if(serviceTerms.isSelected() = false) // line 79
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please accept the terms of service.");
            }
            else
            {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Thanks.");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't want to count down 79 lines: what line is that?

Comment: if(serviceTerms.isSelected() = false) 

it says it in the error.

Comment: I added some more info to my answer that you may find helpful, or interesting, or not...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You have an (illegal) assignment instead of a comparison. Surely you mean:

```
if (serviceTerms.isSelected() == false)
```

Of course the preferential, and more readable, way to write this condition is:

```
if (!serviceTerms.isSelected())
```

Comment: or 
if(!serviceTerms.isSelected())

Comment: Well, that did it. Question answered. Thanks. Ill mark it as correct.

Comment: @Nicholas - nope. In most modern languages = is always an assignment operator, while == is the comparison operator.

Comment: Wait ok, I never thought of it liek that *facepalm*, obviously if its 1 equal you can assign something a boolean value. Thanks very much guys you helped alot!

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you are using the assignment operator `=`.   What you should be using is the equality operator `==` like the following:

```
if(serviceTerms.isSelected() == false) // line 79
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please accept the terms of service.");
}
```

Or, to totally bypass this mistake, you should skip comparing to `false` and use the `!` (not) operator like so.

```
if(!serviceTerms.isSelected()) // line 79
{
    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Please accept the terms of service.");
}
```

I feel this way reads better.

> If not, service terms is selected

That reads more like a sentence than:

> If service terms is selected equals false